# Making views accessible through URL - Drupal

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-views

I have configured the standard "frontpage" view in order to display a list of nodes, just by displaying a field (the banner image).

[image]

Unfortunately the URL /frontapge does not return the previewed template, but the same page that would get displayed before the views module was installed.

---

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you configured the url for the page in the view?

You can make the url to whatever you like. All you need to do, to make it the actual front page, is to write the same url in the front page setting.

Also when it comes to urls and changes in the url system, it's a good idea to clear cache, as it sometimes can be the source to such problems.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to go to admin/settings/site-information and configure the front page setting there to match the url for your view.

also, your screenshot doesn't show it, but I presume you've configured the path param in the page display of the view